# Changing datetime value in python

Tags: python, mongodb, date, datetime

In my Python script I want to change my date value for future time.

In my script I get date values from mongodb. And here is the format.

Datetime taken from mongodb: `2014-09-24 14:32:36.437000`

And as next step I formatted that date value as

```
createdate_mongo_format = "{:%Y-%m-%dT %H:%M:%SZ }".format(createdate_mongo)
```

Result: `2014-09-24T 14:32:36Z`

My question is how can we change the datetime value to next date by only changing the date value all the others are same (Nextdate: `2014-09-25T 14:32:36Z`)? It is better if we can use the datetime value as a parameter and next date by changing that parameter value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`datetime.timedelta()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) to add a day to your `createdate_mongo` value:

```
from datetime import timedelta

createdate_mongo += timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: Martijn, I've been using timedelta for a few days now and I've always just done ` + timedelta(1)` instead of `(days=1)`, can I just ask why you specify days here?

Comment: @JoeSmart: explicit is better than implicit; that way you don't have to look up what the default unit was again. E.g. otherwise you have to remember that `timedelta(1)` is the same as `timedelta(days=1)` and not `timedelta(seconds=1)` or `timedelta(hours=1)`, etc.